# Running several sites from one database

Tags: wordpress

I've setup the following:

1.Tailored wordpress into a cms.

2.Setup the wordpress multisite network across several domains (rather than sub domains).

Now I just want to know is it possible to run several wordpress sites from one database? I have 10 websites and need to run them from one database, what would be the consequences of this?

This is purely down to costs as my host charges per database so I don't want to buy 10 databases (at £25 a time!).

Comment: Possibly related: http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Comment: I'm actually in the process of setting that up, I didn't click they could be connected!! It was more related to hosting costs as they charge per database.

Comment: Great question, I was wondering this for one pet project of mine :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be possible to run multiple Wordpress installations in only one mySQL database. Each installation would use a different table name prefix. From the [installation instructions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_Multiple_Blogs):

> Single Database
>
> As with the multiple databases solution described above, the wp-config.php file will vary for each installation. In this case, however, only a single line will be unique to each blog:
>
> ```
>   $table_prefix = 'wp_'; // example: 'wp_' or 'b2' or 'mylogin_'
> ```
>
> By default, WordPress assigns the table prefix wp_ to its MySQL database tables, but this prefix can be anything you choose. By using more than one, you create unique identifiers for each blog in your database. For example, let's say you have three blogs to set up, with the names Main, Projects and Test. You want to substitute the prefix wp_ for each blog's wp-config.php

Comment: Thanks Pekka, it's all getting a bit confusing! I'm in the process of setting up the wordpress multisite network across several domains rather than sub-domains (in itself quite complicated!). I just want to create a hosting solution for it all with minimum costs (as my host charge per database). Essentially everything will be run by the network with all the websites running from the same database. I guess I could give it a go!

Comment: @Rob I don't know Wordpress MS in detail, but I guess it should be possible to run it from one database. If separate installations can....

Comment: I've setup the network but I've yet to put an additional site into it. Each one has it's own wp-config so guessing this is possible. Would there be any consequences of this? Eventually there would just be a massive database, would this affect the speed of the site?

Comment: @Rob hardly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696682/mysql-many-tables-or-many-databases

Comment: Ok that answers that. So just a question of if it's possible. Just want another view to double check before I jump in! Thanks Pekka!