# Reuse existing database, or use a new one? (for application performance)

Tags: performance, database-design, architecture, content-management-system, oracle11g

I have an existing Oracle 11g DB, with a high transaction volume application running on it. I have another application (a CMS), and am not sure if, performance wise, it makes sense to reuse the existing Oracle DB, or go with a separate database on another physical machine. The two apps share no common data.

My question is: does Oracle 11g (Enterprise) have features which would allow two entirely separate data sets to be accessed simultaneously, with the only performance limitation being the physical/virtual server resources available?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696682/mysql-many-tables-or-many-databases) doesn't apply because my data sets are completely unrelated (and they're on MySQL). I checked out Oracle's suggestions for application performance, but [this paper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/performance/perf-guide-wp-final-133229.pdf) doesn't address optimizing performance for separate applications with separate data sets running on the same database.

Comment: Talking about "performance" without any figures for the current system and what you expect on the CMS is completely futile. Especially with no specs at all on the hardware or the size & shape of the DB. That being said, mixing different workloads on the same database can be hard to tune (for non-trivial loads).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is: no, Oracle doesn't have features to do that kind of separation if don't consider ANY kind of change in you infra-structure.

As far as I can see, your options, with Oracle, would be:

1) Single instance.

1.1) Just one node (your the case now, right!?). Oracle Enterprise scales adding nodes so, this option won't scale and the two schemas/data sets in same database will get in each other way.

1.2) Add more nodes. You can add more nodes to share load (using RAC). Administration would be more complex and licensing costs would go up. But in this case, scalability is only limited by your budget.

2) Two separate instances in separate machines. Equivalent to using a new database in MySql (not minding about the differences in capabilities and pricing).

MySql is inferior to Oracle in many ways but clearly superior in setup costs. Not so sure about maintenence/development costs.

Comment: As far as I know, there is only 1 node/license for the Oracle instance, and I'd like to avoid additional licensing. If there are no other options similar to creating additional nodes, which do not require additional licensing, then a separate MySQL db may be the solution.

Comment: There are no other options. And upgrading HW (CPUs/cores) will also add to licence cost, assuming you don't have per user licensing.